# Repeating a regex pattern multiple times

Tags: javascript, regex

Using JavaScript regexes.

I'm trying to match blocks of text in the form:

```
$Label1: Text1
    Text1 possibly continues 
$Label2: Text2
$Label3: Text3 
     Text3 possibly continues
```

I want to capture the label and the text separately, so that I'll end up with

```
["Label1", "Text1 \n Text1 possibly continues", 
 "Label2", "Text2", 
 "Label3", "Text3 \n Text3 possibly continues"]
```

I've got a regex `\$(.*):([^$]*)` which matches a single instance of the pattern.

I thought maybe something like this: `(?:\$(.*):([^$]*))*` would give me the desired results, but so far I haven't been able to figure out a regex that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the following function:

```
function extractInfo(str) {
    var myRegex = /\$(.*):([^$]*)/gm; 
    var match = myRegex.exec(str);
    while (match != null) {

      var key = match[1];
      var value = match[2];
      console.log(key,":", value);
      match = myRegex.exec(str);
}}
```

Using your example,

```
var textualInfo = "$Label1: Text1\n    Text1 possibly continues \n$Label2: Text2\n$Label3: Text3 \n     Text3 possibly continues";
extractInfo(textualInfo);
```

The results:

```
[Log] Label1 :  Text1
    Text1 possibly continues 

[Log] Label2 :  Text2

[Log] Label3 :  Text3 
     Text3 possibly continues
```

there's a good answer [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression) that explains it all.

Answer (score 2):

You just need the flag `/g` so JavaScript Regex `var re = /\$(.*):([^$]*)/g;`

### [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/kJ3dR0/1)

```
\$(.*):([^$]*)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/aOoEw258DDkX2CJy)

Comment: Matching with `/\$(.*):([^$]*)/g` yields an array with only two values, `['$Label1: Text1 \n Text1 possibly continues ', '$Label2: Text2 $Label3: Text3 Text3 possibly continues' ]`. Does this mean my original regex was wrong?

Comment: @Jephron no your regex is correct, just need to loop over matches.